# Compare two values in two array from two spreadsheet. why not?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-apps-script, multidimensional-array, google-sheets

I would like to compare two values getting from two cell in two different spreadsheet .....but it doesn't run. I don't understand....Logger.log give me same values ....

```
function aggiungiclienti(){
 var fileid = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('FILEID')
 var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet().getRange('B1:B100').getValues()
 var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileid).getRange('A1:A100').getValues()

  Logger.log(ss1[3],ss2[3])
   if(ss1[3] === ss2[3])
   {
     SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Find!')

   Logger.log(ss1[3],ss2[3])
   }  
}
```

Comment: `getValues()` returns 2 dimensional array. So if you want to compare the values of row 3 between `ss1` and `ss2`, please modify `if(ss1[3] === ss2[3])` to ``if(ss1[3][0] === ss2[3][0])` and test it again. But unfortunately, I'm not sure about your goal. So if this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: Perfect!! Thanks! It's right!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing the answer for future viewers. As tanaike said, and according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues):

> (getValues) **Returns a two-dimensional array of values**, indexed by row, then by
>   column. The values may be of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String,
>   depending on the value of the cell. Empty cells are represented by an
>   empty string in the array. Remember that while a range index starts at
>   1, 1, the JavaScript array is indexed from [0][0].

So:
from `if(ss1[3] === ss2[3])` to `if(ss1[3][0] === ss2[3][0])` will get the right value of the array.